# Why is ring matrix's invertibility related to determinant

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm studying module now, and Artin has a statement as follow:

> A square R-matrix $A$ is invertible iff its determinant is a unit of the ring.

I can't understand why out of linear algebra invertibility is still related to determinant.Can you give me some hints? Thanks!

Comment: Remember what happens when you multiply a matrix by its [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix). You get a diagonal matrix with the determinant in the diagonal.

Comment: Well, do you know how to prove this for a field?  The proof for a general commutative ring is similar.

Comment: @user85667 thanks!I got it! I miss this relation!